# batch file picking up files from directory and subdirectories

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a batch file that is appending a date to all to the file name of all CSV files. I only want CSV files in one directory to be picked up and no subdirectories. It appears to be running through all subdirectories though.

I have this code currently in the batch file

```
:: copy files
For /f "delims=" %%a in ('Dir /A:-D /b /s "%LOCALDIR%"*.csv 2^>nul') do If exist "%%a" (
COPY "%%a" "%LOCALDIR%%dtt%-%%~na.csv"
DEL "%%a"
)
```

I have tried getting rid of the /s in the code but then no files are picked up in the directory I want to look for.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure there are folders in the root of the %LOCALDIR%? If it finds them only with `/s` it suggests there are files in subfolders but not in that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a simple loop like?

```
pushd %LOCALDIR%
for %%A in (*.csv) do ren "%%~A" "%dtt%-%%~A"
popd
```

Or for a one liner

```
for %%A in (%LOCALDIR%\*.csv) do ren "%%~A" "%dtt%-%%~A"
```

If the path has spaces in it remember to use the `usebackq` option.